# Docker-Compose: healtcheck script (curl) but Service always (health: starting)

Tags: docker, service, docker-compose

I have the following **docker-compose**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    myprogram-app:
        image: myprogram
        mem_limit: 1024m
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://myprogram-postgresql:5432/myprogram
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
            - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=myprogram-elasticsearch:9300
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=password
            - EMAIL_USERNAME
            - EMAIL_PASSWORD
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        networks:
          - backend
        depends_on:
          jhipster-registry:
            condition: service_healthy
          myprogram-postgresql:
            condition: service_started
          myprogram-elasticsearch:
            condition: service_started
        restart: on-failure
    myprogram-postgresql:
        image: postgres:9.6.5
        mem_limit: 256m
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=myprogram
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myprogram
        networks:
          - backend
    myprogram-elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:2.4.6
        mem_limit: 512m
        networks:
          - backend
    jhipster-registry:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-registry.yml
            service: jhipster-registry
        mem_limit: 512m
        ports:
            - 8761:8761
        networks:
          - backend
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "./isUp", "jhipster-registry:8761"]
          interval: 30s
          retries: 20
networks:
  backend:
    driver: "bridge"
```

and the following script, in the same directory (project root):

```
echo Testing if $1 is UP

http_code=$(curl -LI $1 -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s)

if [ ${http_code} -eq 200 ]; then
    echo The service is UP and Running
    exit 0
else
    echo The service is DOWN
    exit 1
fi
```

The problem I'm facing is that, even after the jhipster-registry service has started, it continues to show me

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                    NAMES
8b16c572e0f2        jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.2.4   "/bin/sh -c 'java   …"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp   compose_jhipster-registry_1
ed86d15ea485        elasticsearch:2.4.6                 "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                      9200/tcp, 9300/tcp       compose_myprogram-elasticsearch_1
f268fa1a11f1        postgres:9.6.5                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                      5432/tcp                 compose_myprogram-postgresql_1
```

even if the service is up and running (I also did a log in on it).

I did also a test, by executing the isUp command on my machine, and it works as expected:

```
izio@1z10:~/Desktop/WorkSpace/myprogram/compose$ ./isUp.sh localhost:8761
Testing if localhost:8761 is UP
The service is UP and Running
izio@1z10:~/Desktop/WorkSpace/myprogram/compose$
izio@1z10:~/Desktop/WorkSpace/myprogram/compose$ echo $?
0
izio@1z10:~/Desktop/WorkSpace/myprogram/compose$
```

Then finally, the registry service becomes unhealthy, having terminated the retries.

```
izio@1z10:~/Desktop/WorkSpace/myprogram/compose$  docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
8b16c572e0f2        jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.2.4   "/bin/sh -c 'java   …"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp   compose_jhipster-registry_1
ed86d15ea485        elasticsearch:2.4.6                 "/docker-entrypoint.…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes               9200/tcp, 9300/tcp       compose_myprogram-elasticsearch_1
f268fa1a11f1        postgres:9.6.5                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes               5432/tcp                 compose_myprogram-postgresql_1
```

Can't get what is wrong with this healthcheck. How to fix it?

Same stuff, using 127.0.0.1:8761

```
test: ["CMD", "./isUp", "127.0.0.1:8761"]
```

or localhost:8761

```
test: ["CMD", "./isUp", "localhost:8761"]
```

Comment: I guess this can be problem with the file permission. just give high permission for testing(like chmod 777) and try.

Comment: I tried chmod +x and chmod 777 but then it returns immediately with unhealty status for the service.

Comment: few thoughts: 1. increase the mem_limit 2. does jhipster-registry has another health checks? 3. print the http_code and add set -x to the script 4. what do you see in the container log when it tries to start and when it unhealthy? 5. increase the interval and add timeout and start_period for the health check

Comment: 1) I did it, but without changes.
2)It simply extends openjdk:8 and installs build-essential as you can see in its dockerfile at https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/blob/master/Dockerfile
Since I have only access to the jhipster-registry.yml and docker-compose.yml, how can I install curl on this image?
3) I did.
4) Nothing in particular, it just takes a while to start, but after max 5 minutes it's up and running, owever still showing as unhealthy in the portainer UI due to the healtcheck not working (I suppose).
5) It's already 10 minutes, and after max 5 it's available.

Comment: as another check that the registry is up and running, I changed         depends_on:
          jhipster-registry:
            condition: service_healthy to service_started
so the app restarts until it finds the registry up. Owever this is just a temp fix since I'd avoid all that restarts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with this `docker-compose` configuration:

1. The `jhipster-registry` is based on `openjdk:8` and doesn't have `curl` installed.
2. The isUp script is not copied to the container's file system, so it's not even executed.

To solve this, the solution I found exploits the base container capabilities.
Since it's **openjdk:8** It's possible to test the service availability through a `Java` program exported in `jar`. So I did.

In the root of the directory, put a **Ping.jar** corresponding to the following class:

```
package ping;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        String host = args[0];
        int port = 0;

        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-2);
        }

        try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 10 * 1000);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then make it available within the `jhipster-registry` container through the volumes field:

```
    jhipster-registry:
    extends:
        file: jhipster-registry.yml
        service: jhipster-registry
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
        - 8761:8761
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/Ping.jar:/Ping.jar
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "java", "-jar", "/Ping.jar", "localhost", "8761"]
      interval: 30s
      retries: 20
```

This way, the service will finally show as **healthy** once it's ready to accept connections:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                              NAMES
b3dd86605278        jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.2.4   "/bin/sh -c 'java   …"    3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp             compose_jhipster-registry_1
```